# Django Admin not working on Azure App service

Tags: django, azure, azure-appservice

I have a Django Restful API hosted on Azure App Server. For Admin page, all static files are generated and place on a folder which configure on settings.py.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

But when try to access admin page from browser static files return with 500 http status code.

Backend logs shows

```
AttributeError: This FileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.
```

Can some one help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are serving static files directly from your project directory. but when deploying to production, it's common to use a web server like Nginx or Apache to serve static files.

I suggest to Update your urls.py like given below

```html
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Already tried, but did not work

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "api/v1/",
        include(
            [
               
            ]
        ),
    )
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)